# undo-tree tree manipulation/cherry picking?

Tags: history, undo, undo-tree-mode

Is it possible to cherrypick changes from different branches in undo tree?

For example say I make a change call it change1.

I then undo, and make a change, call it change2.

I then undo, and make a change, call it change3.

I then undo, and revert to change1. I then realize I infact also want the contents of change3. Is it possible to import it, similiar to gits cherry-pick?

Comment: This would be awesome. You best bet would be to look at how the code for the visualizer `undo-tree-visualizer` works and use this to collect up diffs that you apply in once go.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to say `undo-tree-visualizer-toggle-diff` for viewing diffs.